# JavaScript/ES2015 - Keep all the properties of an object except one whit Rest/Spread operators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this object :

```
const value = {
  "template": "<span translate>myRecommendations</span>",
  "badge": "<span>{{ notifications }}</span>",
  "sref": "recommendation.list"
}
```

I want to use the Rest / Spread operators to create another object with the same name (`value`) with all properties except the `badge` property

Comment: You can't have two variables with the same name.

Comment: FYI, rest/spread **properties** are a proposal, not part of any released ES version.

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```js
const value = {
  "template": "<span translate>myRecommendations</span>",
  "badge": "<span>{{ notifications }}</span>",
  "sref": "recommendation.list"
}

const { badge, ...updatedValue } = value;
console.log(updatedValue)
```

Comment: Good answer, but the new object must be called `value`.

Comment: it should work normally but on the build of the application I have a fatal error `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token` I'm going to find where it comes from

Comment: @MouadEnnaciri: Rest properties are a proposal.

Answer (score 1):

So simply delete that property from the object if you want to keep the another shape in the current variable.

```js
const value = {
  "template": "<span translate>myRecommendations</span>",
  "badge": "<span>{{ notifications }}</span>",
  "sref": "recommendation.list"
};

delete value.badge;

console.log(value);
```

If you need another object you can use object destructing with

```js
const value = {
  "template": "<span translate>myRecommendations</span>",
  "badge": "<span>{{ notifications }}</span>",
  "sref": "recommendation.list"
};

const { badge, ...anotherValue } = value;

console.log(anotherValue);
```

Or iterate over the object keys and get the properties which you want

```js
const value = {
   "template": "<span translate>myRecommendations</span>",
   "badge": "<span>{{ notifications }}</span>",
   "sref": "recommendation.list"
};

const anotherValue = Object.keys(value).reduce((obj, key) => {

  if(key !== 'badge') {
    obj[key] = value[key]    ;
  }
  
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(anotherValue);
```

Comment: I am looking for an alternative to the `delete` operator

Comment: Try the given solutions

Comment: You might want to mention that `const { badge, ...anotherValue } = value;` is a proposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two variables with the same name. However, if you don't want to mutate your original object and still use `spread syntax`, you might consider naming your new object differently, e.g. `value2`.

```js
const value = {
  "template": "<span translate>myRecommendations</span>",
  "badge": "<span>{{ notifications }}</span>",
  "sref": "recommendation.list"
};

const { badge, ...value2 } = value;
    // ^^^^^^ prop you want NOT to include in your new object
console.log(value2);
```

Comment: You might want to mention that rest properties are a proposal. They are not part of ES2015.